# Liquid Simulation How to Stop Interaction with Grid Floor

Tags: physics, fluid-simulation

Honey undesirably and mysteriously interacting with the grid floor. I've tried unchecking the box for grid floor display to no avail. The honey sticks to the underside of the grid floor.
How can I bypass the grid floor here?

The rectangular, animated plates and the 3D plane are Fluid Obstacle objects. 
I will provide any further information deemed necessary.

Thank you.

Comment: Grid Floor in *[Display](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/properties/panels.html#display-panel)* rollout can't affect simulation in any way, it's just for visualization purposes. Fluid simulation can be stuck either in collider objects, too thin objects for current fluid resolution or in the end of fluid domain.

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information on how you set up your project. [Add images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) that might help us understand your scene and settings.